How to send data via Zigbee with esp?
I'm trying to send data or Decryption messages between esp32-h2 modules.

How can I send it?
I edited the code below to send a message. Where am I making a mistake?

main code for sending the message:
#include "esp_log.h" // Include ESP32 logging library
#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h" // Include FreeRTOS library
#include "freertos/task.h" // Include FreeRTOS task management library
#include "ha/esp_zigbee_ha_standard.h" // Include Zigbee Home Automation standard library
#include "main.h" // 
#include "nvs_flash.h" // Include NVS (Non-Volatile Storage) flash library
#include "zcl/zb_zcl_messaging.h" // Include Zigbee ZCL messaging library
#include "zboss_api_aps.h" // Include Zigbee API library

/**
 * @note Make sure the Zigbee component is set as a coordinator device in the idf.py menu configuration!
*/
#if defined ZB_ED_ROLE
#error Define ZB_COORDINATOR_ROLE in the idf.py menu configuration to compile the Zigbee light switch source code.
#endif

/* Define structure for remote device */
typedef struct light_bulb_device_params_s {
    esp_zb_ieee_addr_t ieee_addr; // Device's IEEE address
    uint8_t  endpoint; // Device's endpoint number
    uint16_t short_addr; // Device's short address
    uint8_t  message_length; // Length of the message
    char     message[8]; // Message content (e.g., a field of 50 characters)
} light_bulb_device_params_t;

static const char *TAG = "ESP_ZB_ON_OFF_SWITCH"; // Tag for logging
/* Structure to store and manage remote device information */
light_bulb_device_params_t on_off_light;

void send_hello_message() {
    // Prepare the "Hello" message
    on_off_light.message_length = strlen("Hello"); // Set the message length
    strncpy(on_off_light.message, "Hello", sizeof(on_off_light.message) - 1); // Copy the message

    // ZigBee command to send the display message
    zb_zcl_messaging_display_message_payload_t display_msg_payload;
    display_msg_payload.message_control = 0; // Message control parameter
    display_msg_payload.message_id = 1; // Message ID
    display_msg_payload.start_time = 0; // Start time for displaying the message
    display_msg_payload.duration_in_minutes = 1; // Duration for displaying the message (in minutes)
    strncpy((char *)display_msg_payload.message, on_off_light.message, sizeof(display_msg_payload.message)); // Load the message

    // Send DisplayMessage command
    zb_zcl_messaging_send_display_msg(0, // Parameter
        (const zb_addr_u *)&on_off_light.short_addr, // Target address
        ZB_APS_ADDR_MODE_16_ENDP_PRESENT, // Address mode
        on_off_light.endpoint, // Target endpoint
        HA_ONOFF_SWITCH_ENDPOINT, // Source endpoint
        &display_msg_payload, // Message payload
        NULL // Callback (optional NULL)
    );

    ESP_LOGI("Zigbee", "Hello message sent"); // Log message
}

static void bdb_start_top_level_commissioning_cb(uint8_t mode_mask) {
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_zb_bdb_start_top_level_commissioning(mode_mask)); // Start Zigbee top-level commissioning
}

void user_find_cb(esp_zb_zdp_status_t zdo_status, uint16_t addr, uint8_t endpoint, void *user_ctx) {
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "User find cb: response_status:%d, address:0x%x, endpoint:%d", zdo_status, addr, endpoint); // Log device finding status
    if (zdo_status == ESP_ZB_ZDP_STATUS_SUCCESS) { // If status is successful
        on_off_light.endpoint = endpoint; // Save the endpoint information
        on_off_light.short_addr = addr; // Save the short address information
    }
}

void esp_zb_app_signal_handler(esp_zb_app_signal_t *signal_struct) {
    uint32_t *p_sg_p = signal_struct->p_app_signal; // Get application signal
    esp_err_t err_status = signal_struct->esp_err_status; // Get error status
    esp_zb_app_signal_type_t sig_type = *p_sg_p; // Get signal type
    esp_zb_zdo_signal_device_annce_params_t *dev_annce_params = NULL; // Pointer for device announcement parameters

    switch (sig_type) {
    case ESP_ZB_ZDO_SIGNAL_SKIP_STARTUP:
        ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Zigbee stack initialized"); // Zigbee stack initialized
        esp_zb_bdb_start_top_level_commissioning(ESP_ZB_BDB_MODE_INITIALIZATION); // Start top-level commissioning
        break;
    case ESP_ZB_BDB_SIGNAL_DEVICE_FIRST_START:
    case ESP_ZB_BDB_SIGNAL_DEVICE_REBOOT:
        if (err_status == ESP_OK) { // If error status is successful
            ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Start network formation"); // Starting network formation
            esp_zb_bdb_start_top_level_commissioning(ESP_ZB_BDB_MODE_NETWORK_FORMATION); // Start network formation mode
        } else {
            ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Failed to initialize Zigbee stack (status: %d)", err_status); // Error initializing Zigbee stack
        }
        break;
    case ESP_ZB_BDB_SIGNAL_FORMATION:
        if (err_status == ESP_OK) { // If error status is successful
            esp_zb_ieee_addr_t extended_pan_id; // Extended PAN ID
            esp_zb_get_extended_pan_id(extended_pan_id); // Get extended PAN ID
            ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Formed network successfully (Extended PAN ID: %02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x, PAN ID: 0x%04hx, Channel:%d)",
                     extended_pan_id[7], extended_pan_id[6], extended_pan_id[5], extended_pan_id[4],
                     extended_pan_id[3], extended_pan_id[2], extended_pan_id[1], extended_pan_id[0],
                     esp_zb_get_pan_id(), esp_zb_get_current_channel()); // Log successful network formation
            esp_zb_bdb_start_top_level_commissioning(ESP_ZB_BDB_MODE_NETWORK_STEERING); // Start network steering mode
        } else {
            ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Restart network formation (status: %d)", err_status); // Restarting network formation log
            esp_zb_scheduler_alarm((esp_zb_callback_t)bdb_start_top_level_commissioning_cb, ESP_ZB_BDB_MODE_NETWORK_FORMATION, 1000); // Restart timer
        }
        break;
    case ESP_ZB_BDB_SIGNAL_STEERING:
        if (err_status == ESP_OK) { // If error status is successful
            ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Network steering started"); // Network steering started log
        }
        break;
    case ESP_ZB_ZDO_SIGNAL_DEVICE_ANNCE:
        dev_annce_params = (esp_zb_zdo_signal_device_annce_params_t *)esp_zb_app_signal_get_params(p_sg_p); // Get device announcement parameters
        ESP_LOGI(TAG, "New device commissioned or rejoined (short: 0x%04hx)", dev_annce_params->device_short_addr); // Log new device registered
        esp_zb_zdo_match_desc_req_param_t cmd_req; // Match request parameters
        cmd_req.dst_nwk_addr = dev_annce_params->device_short_addr; // Set target network address
        cmd_req.addr_of_interest = dev_annce_params->device_short_addr; // Set address of interest
        esp_zb_zdo_find_on_off_light(&cmd_req, user_find_cb, NULL); // Find light switch
        break;
    default:
        ESP_LOGI(TAG, "ZDO signal: %d, status: %d", sig_type, err_status); // Log other ZDO signals
        break;
    }
}

static void esp_zb_task(void *pvParameters) {
    /* Initialize Zigbee stack with Zigbee coordinator configuration */
    esp_zb_cfg_t zb_nwk_cfg = ESP_ZB_ZC_CONFIG(); // Zigbee network configuration
    esp_zb_init(&zb_nwk_cfg); // Initialize Zigbee stack
    /* Set up on-off switch device configuration */
    esp_zb_on_off_switch_cfg_t switch_cfg = ESP_ZB_DEFAULT_ON_OFF_SWITCH_CONFIG(); // On-off switch configuration
    esp_zb_ep_list_t *esp_zb_on_off_switch_ep = esp_zb_on_off_switch_ep_create(HA_ONOFF_SWITCH_ENDPOINT, &switch_cfg); // Create endpoint
    esp_zb_device_register(esp_zb_on_off_switch_ep); // Register the device
    esp_zb_set_primary_network_channel_set(ESP_ZB_PRIMARY_CHANNEL_MASK); // Set network channels
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_zb_start(false)); // Start Zigbee
    esp_zb_main_loop_iteration(); // Main loop iteration
    send_hello_message(); // Send "Hello" message
}

void app_main(void) {
    esp_zb_platform_config_t config = { // Zigbee platform configuration
        .radio_config = ESP_ZB_DEFAULT_RADIO_CONFIG(), // Radio configuration
        .host_config = ESP_ZB_DEFAULT_HOST_CONFIG(), // Host configuration
    };
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(nvs_flash_init()); // Initialize NVS flash
    /* Load Zigbee switch platform configuration */
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_zb_platform_config(&config)); // Apply Zigbee configuration
    /* Device setup and initialization */
    xTaskCreate(esp_zb_task, "Zigbee_main", 4096, NULL, 5, NULL); // Create Zigbee task
}

main.h is the code of
#include "esp_zigbee_core.h"


/* Zigbee configuration */
#define MAX_CHILDREN                    10          /* the max amount of connected devices */
#define INSTALLCODE_POLICY_ENABLE       false    /* enable the install code policy for security */
#define HA_ONOFF_SWITCH_ENDPOINT        1          /* esp light switch device endpoint */
#define ESP_ZB_PRIMARY_CHANNEL_MASK     (1l << 13)  /* Zigbee primary channel mask use in the example */

#define ESP_ZB_ZC_CONFIG()                                                              \
    {                                                                                   \
        .esp_zb_role = ESP_ZB_DEVICE_TYPE_COORDINATOR,                                  \
        .install_code_policy = INSTALLCODE_POLICY_ENABLE,                               \
        .nwk_cfg.zczr_cfg = {                                                           \
            .max_children = MAX_CHILDREN,                                               \
        },                                                                              \
    }

#define ESP_ZB_DEFAULT_RADIO_CONFIG()                           \
    {                                                           \
        .radio_mode = RADIO_MODE_NATIVE,                        \
    }

#define ESP_ZB_DEFAULT_HOST_CONFIG()                            \
    {                                                           \
        .host_connection_mode = HOST_CONNECTION_MODE_NONE,      \
    }


I'm trying to send data or a message by editing the code of the LED burning sample.

If it fails, you probably get an error code or an error message. What is it ?
